# LISP Negative Binding

Tags: binding, lisp

I am trying to understand the following LISP code:

```
 (x- (sin q2))
 (x (/ (* m2 x-)
       (+ m1 m2)))
```

Are x- and x separate variables?

Answer (score 2):

yes, in most Lisp dialects you can have symbols with such names. `x-` is a symbol and thus can be used as a variable name.

LispWorks:

```
CL-USER 1 > 'x-
X-

CL-USER 2 > (describe 'x-)

X- is a SYMBOL
NAME          "X-"
VALUE         #<unbound value>
FUNCTION      #<unbound function>
PLIST         NIL
PACKAGE       #<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 57/64 internal, 0/4 external>

CL-USER 3 > (eq 'x- 'x)
NIL
```